# How to create tree.panel grid in ExtJs using one-to-many relationship JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, tree, extjs4

How to create tree.panel grid in ExtJs using one-to-many relationship JSON ?
As I am new to extended JS, whatever i searched and got that for creating tree panel the JSON key(name) of root and child should be same which is given in dataIndex or displayField but in my below json its different,And also as JSON comes from server so how tree panel can know that the node is child node without adding the left key in JSON. Please advise

```
[   
    {
        "plantId": 1,
        "plantLoc": "Vikroli",
        "plantName": "Godrej",
        "plantStrength": 230000,
        "febeOrgs": [{
            "id": {
                "orgId": 9,
                "plantId": 1
            },
            "orgName": "Godrej1",
            "orgSkill": "JAVA"
        }]
    }, 
    {
        "plantId": 2,
        "plantLoc": "Mumbai",
        "plantName": "TCS",
        "plantStrength": 34000,
        "febeOrgs": [{
            "id": {
                "orgId": 6,
                "plantId": 2
            },
            "orgName": "HR",
            "orgSkill": "JAVA"
        }, {
            "id": {
                "orgId": 10,
                "plantId": 2
            },
            "orgName": "Admin",
            "orgSkill": "Python"
        }]
    }
]
```

Here Plant can have many Organisation in that so the tree would be having plant as root node and their respective organisation as there child.